# How to use a variable defined in one variable and use it as an argument in another?

Tags: python-3.x, function, error-handling

I wanted to call use the value of total in the first function and use it as an argument in the other two functions. But it doesn't seem to work as it produces a name error.

```
def all_total():
    '''Calculates and displays the total including
country and s6ales tax'''
    total = float(input('Enter the subtotal of the purchase: '))
    county_tax(total)
    print('County Tax Amount: $'+county_tax())
    state_tax(total)
    print('State Tax Amount: $'+state_tax())
    total += (county_amount + state_amount)

def county_tax(arg1):
    '''Calculates the county tax of the total'''
    county_tax = float(input('Enter the county tax in percent form: '))
    county_amount = county_tax/100*total
    return county_amount

def state_tax(arg1):
    '''Calculates the state tax of the total'''
    state_tax = float(input('Enter the state tax in percent form: '))
    state_amount = state_tax/100*total
    return state_amount

all_total()



Enter the subtotal of the purchase: 200
Enter the county tax in percent form: .025
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Bronx Science/Sophomore/Computer Science_Python/Edwin Chen_Lab 9_Sales Tax.py", line 29, in <module>
    all_total()
  File "E:/Bronx Science/Sophomore/Computer Science_Python/Edwin Chen_Lab 9_Sales Tax.py", line 11, in all_total
    county_tax(total)
  File "E:/Bronx Science/Sophomore/Computer Science_Python/Edwin Chen_Lab 9_Sales Tax.py", line 20, in county_tax
    county_amount = county_tax/100*total
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

Comment: If you are using `total` inside function, what exactly is the use of `arg1` ?

Comment: I thought that you need to have a name for the argument in order for it to work. If I was to type  '''def county_tax()''' with nothing inside, I thought that it probably won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def all_total():
    '''Calculates and displays the total including
country and s6ales tax'''
    total = float(input('Enter the subtotal of the purchase: '))
    county_amount = county_tax(total)
    print('County Tax Amount: ${}'.format(county_amount))
    state_amount = state_tax(total)
    print('State Tax Amount: ${}'.format(state_amount))
    total += county_amount + state_amount

def county_tax(arg1):
    '''Calculates the county tax of the total'''
    county_tax = float(input('Enter the county tax in percent form: '))
    county_amount = county_tax/100*arg1
    return county_amount

def state_tax(arg1):
    '''Calculates the state tax of the total'''
    state_tax = float(input('Enter the state tax in percent form: '))
    state_amount = state_tax/100*arg1
    return state_amount

all_total()
```